# FreeRADIUS 2 traffic counter does not work

Tags: vpn, ppp, radius

I've added this block to radiusd.conf

```
sqlcounter monthlytrafficcounter {
    vcounter-name = Monthly-Traffic
    check-name = Max-Monthly-Traffic
    reply-name = Monthly-Traffic-LIMIT
    sqlmod-inst = SQL
    key = User-Name
    reset = monthly
    query = "SELECT SUM(acctinputoctets + acctoutputoctets) FROM radacct WHERE UserName='%{%k}' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(AcctStartTime) > '%b'"
}
```

and added the dictionary

```
ATTRIBUTE Max-Monthly-Traffic 3003 integer
ATTRIBUTE Monthly-Traffic-Limit 3004 integer
```

then added `monthlytrafficcounter` to `authorize` in `/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default`

but it doesn't work

The `Max-Monthly-Traffic` is defined in MySQL table `radgroupcheck` and the users were added to the group in `radusergroup`

Although a user has reached the traffic limit, he still can be authorized by FreeRadius

[image: reply]